# Repeated web service calls via a proxy web service - performance

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Here's my scenario, I have a nightly batch job that inserts records into a 3rd party system/database. All of these import calls get routed through a proxy service that I created, mainly because my nightly batch job does not have a direct connection to the 3rd party service because of firewalls.

So, I import 10000 records per job run. I establish a connection to my proxy service, where the proxy service establishes a static reference/connection to the 3rd party web service. Right now (don't laugh), I establish the connection for EACH record in my proxy service. That means, I have 10000 "OpenConnection" and "CloseConnection" method calls in my proxy service to accomplish this 1 job run. I run this job twice daily.

My question is, if I establish the connection on the first web service call, but don't close the connection when that first call is made, will subsequent web service calls re-use the existing connection (since it's static)? Or will it re-create another session with the 3rd party service?

If this does work (leaving the connection open for subsequent calls), how do I close the connection when my job is done so I can free my managed (or is it unmanaged) resources? I don't want to add a method in my own web service called "CloseConnection"...

In addition to that, our servers do automatic IIS RESETS on a nightly basis, if the connection is still open at that time, will it dispose of my connection properly?

Sorry, LOTS of questions here, just looking for a "best practice" approach to accomplishing my task of speeding up this process.

I'll try and give a code example of this, here's the batch job code:

```
ws.EstablishConnection();

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10000; counter++)
{
   ws.ImportRecord(myRecords[counter]);
}

ws.Dispose();
```

Web service code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ImportRecord(MyRecord myRecord)
{
   try
   {
      OpenConnection();
      _3rdPartyWS.ImportRecord(myRecord);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
   finally
   {
      CloseConnection();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if I establish the connection on the first web service call, but don't close the connection when that first call is made, will subsequent web service calls re-use the existing connection (since it's static)?

If it is static, the same object will be used. But you won't gain much speed.  Watch out because "open" connection may time-out.

> Or will it re-create another session with the 3rd party service?

Web Services are "session-less" each call will be in it's own session.

> If this does work (leaving the connection open for subsequent calls),
>   how do I close the connection when my job is done so I can free my
>   managed (or is it unmanaged) resources? I don't want to add a method
>   in my own web service called "CloseConnection"...

Your connection object is Static... you can't close connection without calling explicitly "closeConnection.

> In addition to that, our servers do automatic IIS RESETS on a nightly
>   basis, if the connection is still open at that time, will it dispose
>   of my connection properly?

The "pool idle" timeout may pass before the nightly base IISReset.  The garbage collector will dispose every memory used on your side.  The 3rd party may never received the close() request but it would certainly close the connection after some time.

The best thing you could do in your case is implement a web service method that receive an array of MyReccord.  You will save a lot of time there.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ImportRecord(MyRecord[] myRecords)
{
   try
   {
      OpenConnection();
      for (int counter = 0; counter < myRecords.Length; counter++)
      {
         3rdPartyWS.ImportRecord(myRecords[counter]);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      CloseConnection();
   }
}
```

A better case would be, if possible, ask your 3rd party to implement a web method that receive an array of object or a file.

Web Services loop are very slow you should never do this.

Comment: Thanks @Guish "Your connection object is Static... you can't close connection without calling explicitly "closeConnection", is it possible to implement some kind of Dispose method in here? "Watch out because "open" connection may time-out." I left out some code, in the OpenConnection() method in MY web service, I check to see if the _3rdParyWS is already instantiated and connected, if it's not, then it re-establishes the connection. In my current setup, it would re-establish everytime.

Comment: So If I don't call the CloseConnection() method at the end, would it then see that the _3rdParyWS is already instantiated and connected, and skip that step then? I thought about doing this, but I get response/error code return values for each individual import call with the status of the import. I guess I could go this route also and just change my ImportDocumentResult object to an array instead of a single instance. I'll see if I can't get that to work. Thanks for th help!

Comment: If your connection object is declared "Static" then it is shared for all objects in your application pool.  Your 3rd party partner may limit the maximum number of open connections.  Leaving a connection open will "use" 1 of the maximum number of connection.  You should always close your connection to keep things clean but a connection will shut itself after a certain timeout.  Reusing the same "Static" connection object shouldn't use a new connection.